# Change File Name with Session Variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the below code which works fine, but I would like to change the file name with session("MyFileName") variable value which I don't know how to edit.

```
function onUploadClick() {
if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
    var filename = fileExists();
    if (filename == '') {
        //Update the message
        updateMessage(MessageStatus.Information, 'Initializing upload ...', '', '0 of 0 Bytes');
        //Submit the form containing the fileupload control
        form.submit();
        //Set transparancy 20% to the frame and upload button
        Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass($get('dvUploader'), 'StartUpload');
        //Initialize progressbar
        setProgress(0);
        //Start polling to check on the progress ...
        startProgress();
        intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
        PageMethods.GetUploadStatus(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                setProgress(result.percentComplete);
                //Upadte the message every 500 milisecond
                updateMessage(MessageStatus.Information, result.message, result.fileName, result.downloadBytes);
                if (result == 100) {
                    //clear the interval
                    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
                    clearTimeout(subintervalID);
                }
            }
        });
        }, 500);
    }
    else
        onComplete(MessageStatus.Error, "File name '<b>" + filename + "'</b> already exists in the list.", '', '0 of 0 Bytes');
}
else
    onComplete(MessageStatus.Warning, 'You need to select a file.', '', '0 of 0 Bytes');
}
```

Also I need to replace the file if it exists.

Comment: Is this webforms or Razor? In webforms use `var filename = '<%= Session["MyFileName"].ToString() %>'`, in Razor use `var filename = '@Session["MyFileName"].ToString()'`.

Comment: It is Webform.  I don't know where to implement your suggestion :(

Comment: What is the content of `fileExists()`? Well, putting `var filename = '<%= Session["MyFileName"].ToString() %>';` just enough after `fileUpload.value.length` check. What I still not understand is how you want to *replace the file if it exists*.

Comment: This is the actual Source Code link  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113418/ASP-NET-File-Upload-with-Progress-Bar

Comment: Please avoid Visual Studio tags unless your question specifically pertains to the Visual Studio IDE (as opposed to code written within). If you need to tag a specific version of the language, or framework, please use the c# and net-framework tags instead.

Comment: @ John, Thanks for the modification and intimation.

Comment: "What I still not understand is how you want to replace the file if it exists." In general VB.Net replaces the file when you upload it.  This is a Java-Script so I don't know how to make this to work like VB.Net code :(

Comment: Well, at least you can provide contents of `fileExist` method which suspects to check file existence, so that anyone knows the purpose of that method. Replacing a file in server-side usually involves callback which either overwriting or deleting previous version then create new one with same name.